# Export PDF data for an ECG from health app using siwft

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I have an application which gets data from health app and but the data i got from healthkit is not in visual  form. So is there any way i can get the "Export to pdf" functionality from health  in my app ?
I have added sample code using which i am getting data.

```
  for sample in ecgSamples {
            // Handling the samples here.
            print("Sampel Data: \(sample)")

            let voltageQuery = HKElectrocardiogramQuery(sample) { (query, result) in
                switch(result) {

                case .measurement(let measurement):
                    if let voltageQuantity = measurement.quantity(for: .appleWatchSimilarToLeadI) {
                        // Handling the voltage quantity here.
                        print("Voltage Data: \(voltageQuantity)")

                    }

                case .done:
                    print("Voltage Data Complete")
                    // No more voltage measurements. Finish processing the existing measurements.

                case .error(let error):
                    print("Voltage error: \(error)")                        // Handle the error here.

                }
            }

            // Execute the query.
            self.healthStore.execute(voltageQuery)

        }
```

Comment: get data with completion handler to a controller try to visualize with PDFView after that you can save pdf document in files

Comment: You would have to create a visual representation of the ECG first. The query only returns sets of voltages, so a list of numbers.

Comment: the data set i got from query did not have time info for each voltage? Is there any way you guys did this or any lib that i can use to do visual representation.
@johnelemans

Comment: The docs say that the frequency is given, so you know the time space between samples; https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkelectrocardiogram

Comment: @johnelemans was able to show data on a chart as an ECG, but still stuck at the part of exporting it to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a long time i came across this project which allows user to show data from ECG to your iOS app.
[iOS ECG App](https://github.com/apooreapo/hkelectrocardiogram-example-iOS)
once you are able to show data its not hard to take that chart to pdf.
You might face an issue with scrolling of chart so you can either try your own scroll or move function of map.